# Different FileOpenModes using design automation for AutoCAD

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I seem to have issues sometimes opening a drawing database.  In the past, I used: MyDb.ReadDwgFile(DrawingName, IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, True, Nothing), with the IO.Fileshare.ReadWrite being the point of interest.  But, I started having issues with it when I moved to Design Automation.  I Later, I found a different file open mode enum of FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndAllShare and started using it.

I understand both enums are from different libraries (system.io vs autodesk.autocad.databaseservices), but why do I have off and on success using one versus the other?  Could it be because of the .dwg version, or because AEC libraries are being loaded?  I switched to the autodesk enum and was having success for a while, but now I have some files that pass though and others that don't.  For right now, my plan is to try one, check for a failure, then try the other.  Is anybody else running into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is specific to Design Automation. I think the same DWG file will behave the same on your machine too. I suspect what's going on is that you have some unreadable objects in the drawing. ReadWrite will engage the "lazy loading" code path: only the objects that you open are loaded from disk. "...AllShare" will load every object from disk since you want others to be able to access the drawing simultaneously.

Comment: First, thanks for explaining the difference; I didn't know that.  But I've been using ReadWrite for a decade now, and don't have issues with it on the same drawings I'm running through DA.  I only switched to AllShare because of issues using ReadWrite in DA.  Right now, I've placed a Trace statement before and after each approach, the first being caught in a Try-Catch, the second in the Catch.  I'll post the results after I run it.

Comment: Well, the Try-Catch crap didn't work very well, but recognizing I had grabbed an updated set of drawing to work with this morning, I decided to investigate them per your suggestion, and yeah, there was a butt load of crap in them. Anyway, thanks for the tip.